# How does one use a single PR for multiple issues?

Tags: git, jira

Some background: large ruby project through jira and bitbucket

There are multiple issues that can be solved with adding a single function and then calling that function in the various issues through a before_action or something on a controller. I have a single PR for one of the issues which adds that function in the main application_controller.rb and adds the before_filter in one of the controllers.

In the other issues, how does one then reference that PR which adds that main function in application_controller.rb while at the same time putting the before_filter in the associated controllers for that specific issue?

My git-fu is lacking.

Answer (score 1):

Just mention your other jira with the key in the description of the pull request.
Jira will automatically track that pull request